# Presentation time in ALSA

Tags: timestamp, embedded-linux, alsa, pcm, audio-video-sync

I am receiving IEEE 1722 standard ethernet packets from a machine over the network. These packets contain a 'timestamp' field which can be used by the receiver to decide when to play the audio data using ALSA subsystem.
I want to know whether which API or parameter (in ALSA) I can use to fulfil this requirement. I am using Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the timestamp from alsa, use api snd_pcm_status_get_tstamp(). I think you need to read the presentation timestamp recived and alsa timestamp and decide on logic weather to play the audio, rewind or to skip the packets.